# The maximum order of an element of $A_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> The maximum order of an element of $A_{10}$, the group of even permutations on 10 symbols, can have is: a) 30;  b) 15;  c) 10;  d) 20.

My answer is option b) 15 as $\operatorname{lcm}\{3,5,1,1\}=15$ and $10=3+5+1+1$.
Am I right?

Comment: How about a product of $3$-cycle and $7$-cycle?

Comment: 21=l.c.m{7,3} and also 3+7=10..But in my question there is no option for 21.so if I chose 15 then is it  correct?

Comment: Can you find three numbers adding to 10 whose lcm is 30?

Comment: yes.i have found..10=2+3+5 and l.c.m of {2,3,5}=30 and it is odd permutation..

Comment: The correct answer to the question is $21$. So none of the options you were given is correct. Bad luck!